# Meaning and usage of "a bull in a china shop"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

While I can kinda guess the meaning of the idiom *a bull in a china shop*, I would like to learn the proper meaning.

And in what situations can I use this idiom properly?

Comment: You are supposed to do some research first.

Comment: However, it means a clumsy person, as in *He felt like a bull in a china shop; reaching for an orange, he made several elaborate pyramids of fruit tumble down.*

Comment: See The Free Dictionary, Idioms  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+a+bull+in+a+china+shop

Comment: Did you Google "bull in a china shop"?  Did you even try to envision what it might mean?

Comment: @haha - Not necessarily clumsy, just careless and destructive.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***[bull in a china shop](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bull+in+a+china+shop)*** is an old saying meaning :

> - Clumsily destructive.

Etymology

> An early written example of the expression appeared in Frederick Marryat's 1834 novel, Jacob Faithful , although ***the image of a bull wrecking havoc as he wandered among tables and shelves of fine porcelain can be traced a century earlier.***

Related information:

> ***The expression can also be found in several European languages, although the animal in question is an elephant.***
>
> In 1940, an American press agent led a bull through a New York City china shop as a publicity stunt. The bull didn't break anything, but a bystander trying to avoid the bull backed into a table and caused the damage.

(Endangered Phrases)

See also from Word Wild Words, [Bull in a china shop](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bul4.htm).